# PHP is echoing text from json value in a one paragraph where as the JSON Value is having multiple line spaces

Tags: php, json, youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch data from my youtube channel to my website using Youtube data api and PHP.

I am not asking here how to print text from json array. But I am asking how to print a text as it is. Please look into following images.

[Image from chrome element console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeLHy.png)

[Image from PHP webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OvYZ.png)

The first image, is from my webpage. It is printing description of my youtube video. I collecting this video from JSON Array and the code is:

```
<?php echo $details["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"];?>
```

But if I check in the chrome console, element section:
The text is exactly as it is in my youtube video description. (Please look at the second image)

I want to print the text as it is in the description (as it appears in the second image).

I hope you have understood the issue. Please guide me how to solve the issue.

Comment: I think the images are the same

Comment: Text whitespace is collapesd in *HTML context*, unless your CSS tells otherwise or you use `nl2br()` with the echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution. If any one come across the same issue, it might help.

Initially, I was echoing the text but it has its own format. PHP echo was ignoring the format of the text. Here goal is to keep the format of the text. Therefore we are required to wrap the text in `<pre></pre> tags`

This tag would print the text from source as it is.

```
<?php echo '<pre>'.$details["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"].'</pre>';?>
```